# Can't upload to BigQuery with API of JSON data

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Sorry for my very novice question. I am new to python and BigQuery, and I am trying to make a simple viz in Data Studio using an API.

I have python script below that tries to get JSON data from a public API loaded into Google BigQuery. I am not able to get the JSON data uploaded to BigQuery.

I think one of my problems is that the data is coming in as comma separated instead of new line. Is it possible to write in the code to break the data in new lines?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import urllib
import json
import urllib.request
import requests

from google.cloud import bigquery

def createdataset():

    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()

    dataset_id = 'mydataset'

    dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_id)
    dataset = bigquery.Dataset(dataset_ref)

    dataset = bigquery_client.create_dataset(dataset)

    print('Dataset {} created.'.format(dataset.dataset_id))

def main():
    fetch_traffic_data()
    load_json("data.json")

def fetch_traffic_data():

    URL = "https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/8v9j-bter.json"


def send_to_big_query(data):
    BIG_QUERY_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/bigquery-test-205619/datasets"
for d in data:

    print(d)
    response = requests.post(BIG_QUERY_URL, data=json.dumps(d))
    print(response.text)
    #post each dictionary (JSON data point) to big query

def load_json(source_file_name):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset = bigquery_client.dataset('mydataset')
    table = dataset.table('mytable')

    with open(source_file_name, 'rb') as source_file:

        job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
        job_config.source_format = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON'
        job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_file(
        source_file, table, job_config=job_config)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Also, is it possible to get this code to run semi regularly?

Thank you so much for your help, again I apologize with the novice question.

Comment: Is this your full code? Because I think that you are never executing "def send_to_big_query(data):" function.  I'm right?

Comment: This is my full code, I think you are correct. Where would I execute the function?